# Pythagorean Theorem - Incomplete proof

Tags: geometry, pythagorean-triples

The image below is supposed to prove Pythagorean Theorem (without words). However, I see that it is assuming that the square of side $c$ can be inscribed in the square of side $a+b$ and would result in the $4$ triangles of equal area. This fact is only assumed, so would the proof be considered incomplete?

[image]

Comment: For a proof without words this is complete. The fact that the yellow square can be inscribed is a simple consequence of symmetry.

Comment: I'd come at it the other way an say that there is no embedded square there are only 4 triangles.  Then putting them together makes the square.  The triangles form right angles for the same reason gradients of perpendicular lines.

Comment: You don’t even have to inscribe it. Start with the yellow square, then add the pink triangles to it.

Comment: The complementary angles plus the right angle of the yellow square sum to a straight angle.  In this context, a proof without words is intended to provoke an easy thought process to complete it.

Comment: Surely, the main idea is shown in the picture, and many people would say that it is easy to complete the proof from this picture. But it is debatable, whether it can be considered to be "complete" , a quite subjective word in this context anyway.

Comment: Nevertheless, a very elegant variation of a proof of the pythagorean theorem.

Comment: The proof tacitly makes use of the additivity of the area function, which is by no means trivial.

Comment: @Karl, I guess your point is excellent (I can get it)...May be this is the key.

Comment: The answer below shows an important part that I missed : It must also be shown that the yellow figure is actually a square. It may be not very difficult to show this (I leave it to everyone to decide him/herself) , but it is also a necessary part to complete the proof. Considering this, I wouldn't call this picture-proof "complete".

Comment: @Peter, thanks for your comment. I agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem :

In a right triangle with legs $a,b$ and hypothenuse $c$:

$a^2+b^2=c^2.$

Geometric proof:

Consider a square of side length $a+b$ (drawing).

Partition the sides into $a$ and $b$ as shown.

Each of the $4$ corner triangles formed are congruent by $SAS$, i.e. $a,b$, and right angle between.

Hence the quadrilateral formed by connecting the partition  points has $4$ equal sides $c$, a rhombus.

The adjacent sides of the inner quadrilateral are perpendicular (why?).

Hence the inner quadrilateral is a square.

Area of outer square of side length $a+b:$

$A:= (a+b)^2.$

Also:

$A= 4(1/2)ab  + c^2$, where $(1/2)ab$  is the area of one triangle (why?).

Finally:

$a^2+b^2 = c^2$.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am not sure if you have answered the question...The tricky part is that it is not obvious to me that when you partition a line into two parts at each side and you connect the partition point, you get a square.

Comment: NoChance.Thought the above proves your point. The inscribed quadrilateral has 4 l sides of equal length c. Rhombus. The angle between adjacent sides is 90°. Hence?

Comment: Got it thanks...